# Cuestiones sobre SOCKS

Tags: c++

Hola tengo unas cuantas cuestions sobre SOCKS. Necesito saber primero su utilidad y una explicación breve que defina exactamente sobre lo que son se que son proxies que se utilizan para el anonimato no se si sea la mejor definición. Por otra parte, necesito saber que significa (JID of your SOCKS5 proxy.) Como lo puedo conseguir o sacarlo. ¿Se pueden obtener estos SOCKS o crearse uno propio? Nada más. Si lo pongo en c++ porque no me deja usar la etiqueta SOCKS y no se me ocurre otra.

Answer (score 3):

**SOCKS**

Es un protocolo de Internet que permite a las aplicaciones Cliente-servidor usar de manera transparente los servicios de un firewall de red. SOCKS es una abreviación de "SOCKetS".

Los clientes que hay detrás de un firewall que necesitan acceder a los servidores del exterior, pueden conectarse en su lugar a un servidor proxy SOCKS. Tal servidor proxy controla qué cliente puede acceder al servidor externo y pasa la petición al servidor. SOCKS puede ser usado también de la forma contraria, permitiendo a los clientes de fuera del firewall ("clientes exteriores") conectarse a los servidores de dentro del firewall (servidores internos).

El protocolo fue desarrollado originalmente por David Koblas, un administrador de MIPS Computer Systems. Después de que MIPS fuera controlado por Silicon Graphics en 1992, Koblas presentó un artículo sobre SOCKS en el Simposio anual de seguridad Usenix y SOCKS llegó a estar disponible públicamente.

**SOCKS5**

Una extensión del protocolo SOCKS 4 que ofrece más opciones de autenticación. La negociación (handshake) inicial ahora consiste en lo siguiente:

> ● El cliente se conecta y envía un saludo en el cual incluye una lista de los métodos de autenticación soportados.
> ● El servidor escoge uno (o envía una respuesta de fallo si ninguno de los métodos ofrecidos es aceptable).
> ● Algunos mensajes pueden pasar ahora entre el cliente y el servidor dependiendo del método de autenticación escogido.
> ● El cliente envía una petición de conexión similar a  SOCKS4.
> ● El servidor responde de manera similar a SOCKS4.

Los métodos de autenticación soportados son enumerados como sigue:

> ● 0x00 - Sin autenticación
> ● 0x01 - GSSAPI
> ● 0x02 - Nombre de Usuario/Password
> ● 0x03..0x7F - métodos asignados por IANA
> ● 0x80..0xFE - métodos reservados para uso privado

El saludo inicial desde el cliente es:

> ● campo 1: número de versión socks, debe ser 0x05 para esta versión
> ● campo 2: número de métodos de autenticación soportados, 1 byte
> ● campo 3: métodos de autenticación, longitud variable, 1-byte por método soportado

La elección del servidor es comunicada:

> ● campo 1: versión socks, 1 byte, 0x05 para esta versión
> ● campo 2: método de autenticación escogida, 1 byte, o 0xFF cuando no sean ofrecidos métodos aceptables.

La autenticación subsiguiente es dependiente del método. La petición de conexión del cliente es:

> ● campo 1: número de versión socks, 1 byte, debe ser 0x05 para esta versión
> ● campo 2: código de comando, 1 byte:
>       • 0x01 = establecer una conexión stream tcp/ip
>       • 0x02 = establecer  un enlazado(binding) de puerto tcp/ip
>       • 0x03 = asociar un puerto udp
> ● campo 3: reservado, debe ser 0x00
> ● campo 4: tipo de dirección, 1 byte:
>       • 0x01 = dirección IPV4 (el campo de direcciones tiene una longitud de 4 bytes)
>       • 0x03 = Nombre de dominio (el campo dirección es variable)
>       • 0x04 = dirección IPV6 (el campo de direcciones tiene una longitud de 16 bytes)
> ● campo 5: dirección destino, 4/16 bytes o longitud de nombre 1+dominio.
>       • Si el tipo de dirección es 0x03 entonces la dirección consiste en un byte de longitud seguido del nombre de dominio.
> ● campo 6: número de puerto en el orden de bytes de la red, 2 bytes

Respuesta del Servidor:

> ● campo 1: versión de protocolo socks, 1 byte, 0x05 para esta versión
> ● campo 2: estado, 1 byte:
>       • 0x00 = petición concedida, 
>       • 0x01 = fallo general,
>       • 0x02 = la conexión no se permitió por el conjunto de reglas(ruleset)
>       • 0x03 = red inalcanzable
>       • 0x04 = host inalcanzable
>       • 0x05 = conexión rechazada por el host destino
>       • 0x06 = TTL expirado
>       • 0x07 = comando no soportado/ error de protocolo
>       • 0x08 = tipo de dirección no soportado
> ● campo 3: reservado, 0x00
> ● campo 4: tipo de dirección, 1 byte:
>       • 0x01 = dirección IPV4 (el campo de direcciones tiene una longitud de 4 bytes)
>       • 0x03 = Nombre de dominio (el campo dirección es variable)
>       • 0x04 = dirección IPV6 (el campo de direcciones tiene una longitud de 16 bytes)
> ● campo 5: dirección destino, 4/16 bytes o longitud de nombre 1+dominio.
>       • Si el tipo de dirección es 0x03 entonces la dirección consiste en un byte de longitud seguido del nombre de dominio.

Puedes adquirir servicios de SOCKS5 de diferentes proveedores en la web.

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué son los Sockets? Pues un concepto utilizado en la comunicación de ordenadores y procesos. Una buena deficinión la tienes en la propia wikipedia: [Socket](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_de_Internet).

Los programas informáticos usan sockets para comunicarse, por lo tanto están directamente relacionados con la navegación en internet. *Cuando ves una página web desde tu navegador lo que está sucediendo es que tu programa navegador "ha abierto un socket" hacia un programa servidor y através de ese socket recibes la información de la página web en cuestion.*

**Si lo que te interesa es el anonimato** y estás interesado en usar un proxy que te ofrezca ese anonimato... te recomiendo que busques en internet sobre [Tor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(red_de_anonimato)). Es un programa/red que ofrece un buen grado de anonimato/encriptado de las comunicaciones.

Sobre el problema concreto que tienes con "algún programa" y los [SOCKS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) pues la wikipedia te pude esclarecer un poco, aunque sería muy interesante que explicaras que programa estás intentando usar y qué es lo que pretendes para que podamos ayudarte mejor ;-)